# Unable to load the podcast's feed in Rhythmbox

Tags: networking, rhythmbox, podcast

I try to use Rhythmbox for podcasts. I can search podcasts by names and authors  but when I try to subscribe them (for some feeds) Rhythmbox shows this error "Unable to load the feed - Check your network connection".

First Step:
[image: First Step]

Second Step:[image: Second Step]

I checked my connection and also tried some VPN connections but didn't work. In the same WAN I used podcast addict on my android phone and I have no problem with these podcast feeds.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Not really sure that will be any help given the year this has been posted and the pictures displayed, but I landed here because I was experiencing a similar issue. It turns out rhythmbox doesn't "like" searching for full URLs (e.g. an Apple podcast URL) and the interface design is terrible at giving you feedback. My solution was to only use the Apple podcast ID in the search box, after that and some more acrobatics around the interface, I was able to start downloading episodes. In case this may help anyone out there...

Answer (score -1):

OK, I think my previous answer may have been a bit hasty. I did some more digging for you, and here is what I found out.

1. Subscribe to the feed that you want. In my case, the example I used was 7 podcasts for Linux users. [image: Show_Feed]
2. In this example, I clicked on "Show Feed".
3. Then there was an option that said "All Shows Audio".
4. Finally it was just a matter of copy and paste. Here is another screenshot of the website feed I copied.[image: Website_Feed] Now go to Rhythmbox and click on Podcasts. In the search bar, paste in the link that you want. Next, click search, and then subscribe. [image: Rhythmbox]
5. This [website](http://www.linuceum.com/Desktop/PodcastReceive.php#topic4) was helpful in getting answers for you. I hope this helps.